# Error usando require_once

Tags: php

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo un archivo index.php el cual tiene un login que envía la información "controller/login.php" el cual tiene dentro estos dos `require_once`

```
require_once 'conx/Db.php';
require_once '../libs/Security.php';
```

la raíz de los archivos es la siguiente:

```
index.php
dashboard.php
controller/
|---->conx/Db.php
|---->login.php
libs/
|---->Security.php
```

Que pasa, cuandome logueo en el sistema ingresa perfectamente pero al momento de llegar a `dashboad.php` me lanza este error:

```
Warning: require_once(../libs/Security.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\internacionalPeritaciones\controller\login.php on line 4
```

Lo que no entiendo es por que antes de entrar a `dashboard.php` funciona perfectamente pero cuando ingreso me lanza ese error y ambos archivos index y dashboard están en la misma carpeta. Traté usando:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .  '/libs/Security.php';
------ por separado
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $root . '/libs/Security.php';
```

Ninguno de esos me funcionaron, la verdad estoy un poco perdido. Se les agradece la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

**En teoría**, para evitar problemas, es mejor usar rutas absolutas. Se adaptan mejor a cualquier implementación.

Teniendo en cuenta la ruta absoluta de tu sistema hasta el `root` de la aplicación:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\internacionalPeritaciones
```

Deberías probar con lo siguiente:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/conx/Db.php';
require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/libs/Security.php';
```

`__DIR__` va a apuntar siempre (en este script y dentro de esta estructura) a `C:\xampp\htdocs\internacionalPeritaciones\controller`

*En Windows no recuerdo como se armaban las rutas con barras normales o invertidas.*

Por lo que solo habrá que teminar de enlazar el script desde ese punto:

```
/conx/Db.php
```

Y `dirname( __DIR__ )` apunta a un directorio menos, viene a ser lo mismo que hacer `__DIR__ . '/../libs/Security.php'`.

Así que nos dejaría en el root `C:\xampp\htdocs\internacionalPeritaciones`.

Haciendo lo mismo que en el punto anterior, solo hay que enlazar el otro script:

```
/libs/Security.php
```

Esto no debería darte problemas, incluso si cambias el entorno. Pero si, lógicamente, si cambias la estructura actual del `root`.

> Como nota, tanto `__DIR__` como `dirname()` terminan las rutas sin la `/` al final. Por lo que tanto para avanzar en los directorios `/dir/...`, como para salir de ellos `/../dir/...` hay que armar la ruta empezando con una barra `/`.

Si no me he equivocado al redactarlo, debería solucionar el problema.

En caso contrario, danos más información de como envías la info a `login.php` y muestra las partes críticas del código que intervienen para ver mejor que puede estar ocurriendo.

Comment: Si, de esa manera fue que pude solucionarlo usando la ruta absoluta.. muchas gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 2):

El error este:

```
Warning: require_once(../libs/Security.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\internacionalPeritaciones\controller\login.php on line 4
```

Es porque no encuentra el archivo en la ruta indicada. Si tienes la siguiente ruta:

```
index.php
dashboard.php
controller/
|---->conx/Db.php
|---->login.php
libs/
|---->Security.php
```

Y tu estas en dashboard, para acceder a `libs`, no puedes poner `../` antes de la ruta, ya que estarias retrocediendo un nivel en las carpetas, para acceder a `libs` desde `dashboard`, tendrias que ponerlo asi:

```
require_once 'libs/Security.php';
```

o asi:

```
require_once '/libs/Security.php';
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Buenas noches trate usando ambas formas y no me pasa del login, solo pasa del login usando esta require_once '../libs/Security.php'; y una vez que entra a dashboard si la cambias a esta require_once '/libs/Security.php'; entonces no da error pero pasa que entonces no te puedes loguear de nuevo