# Warning: file_put_contents(src/Entity/"clientes".php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (SYMFONY)

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

Hola a todo el mundo :)

Al realizar el comando "php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import 'App\Entity' annotation --path=src/Entity", para mapear la informacion de la base de datos (CON POSTGRESQL) y pasarlo a un archivo .php para majeras la información, me da este ERROR.
Ya lo hice anteriormente con MYSQL y todo fue bien, ahora no se cual es el problema.

Muchas gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Básicamente te dice que el archivo no existe, así que revisa si la ruta hacia el archivo es correcta. Por lo que veo en el error estás usando rutas relativas. Quizás esto te puede ayudar: [Ejemplo de rutas absolutas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23133/5984), [otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75917/5984).

Comment: Es llamativo que te marque "clientes" entre comillas... ¿estás tratando de armar las entidades a partir de la estructura que ya tienes en la db?

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. El problema era que de la bbdd me estaba cogiendo la tabla "cliente" con comillas en vez de sin comillas, y claro. "clintes".php no se puede escribir. Solo quité las comillas ya que Postgre se lo ha comido y a funcionar!! Gracias!!